# XIB loads with black Screen from pushViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a Storyboard which loads a XIB with a TableView inside.

[image: XIB with TableView]

When the user selects a row from the TableView a new XIB should be loaded with the following method pushViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    RecipeDetailViewController *recipeDetailViewController = [[RecipeDetailViewController alloc] init];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
    recipeDetailViewController.navTitle = str;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipeDetailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The loaded new XIB should show the following View (with a button inside):

[image]

Instead it loads a black view like below:

[image]

I checked whether the view is connected to the viewcontroller. From my point of view everything is fine. In IB it the view is connected the File's Owner:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. All I had to do is to close XCode and reopen the project. After that all worked just fine!